# Unable to detect the middle of the lane

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I was able to detect the lanes but i have to also detect the middle/center of the lane i.e. center/middle of two lines. i tried the middle of x1 and x2 but it didnt work. i want a third line i.e. middle line. i have also attached the screenshot

```
  def houghLines(cropped_canny):
    return cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_canny, 2, np.pi/180, 100, 
        np.array([]), minLineLength=70, maxLineGap=5)

def addWeighted(frame, line_image):
    return cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.8, line_image, 1, 1)
 
def display_lines(img,lines):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(img)
    if lines is not None:
        print(len(lines))
        for line in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                #print(len(lines))
                cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),5)
    return line_image



cap = cv2.VideoCapture("videoplayback (online-video-cutter.com) (1).mp4")
while(cap.isOpened()):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    canny_image = canny(frame)
    cropped_canny = region_of_interest(canny_image)
    #cv2.imshow("cropped_canny",cropped_canny)

    lines = houghLines(cropped_canny)
    #averaged_lines = average_slope_intercept(frame, lines)
    line_image = display_lines(frame, lines)
    combo_image = addWeighted(frame, line_image)
    
    
    cv2.imshow("result", combo_image)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What equation did you use to get the middle line from the two red lines?  You should get the equations of the lines from end points and combine the equations (combine slopes and combine intercepts) to get the line for the middle.

Answer (score 1):

i have no idea, if you can detect it somehow with opencv, but you could just calculate it by averaging the (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) coordinates of every line.

e.g.:

```py
def display_midline(img, lines):
    line_image = np.zero_like(img)
    x1_avg, y1_avg = (0, 0)
    x2_avg, y2_avg = (0, 0)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                x1_avg += x1
                y1_avg += y1
                x2_avg += x2
                y2_avg += y2
        x1_avg = int(x1_avg / len(lines))
        y1_avg = int(y1_avg / len(lines))
        x2_avg = int(x2_avg / len(lines))
        y2_avg = int(y2_avg / len(lines))
        cv2.line(line_image, (x1_avg, y1_avg), (x2_avg, y2_avg), (0, 0, 255), 5)
    return line_image
```